# Django , Query to get certain values with a distinct name and the latest date and time

Tags: mysql, django

The situation is i have a database full of test results split into different test sets. Each test has a name, result , start time , start date , ... , what currently happens is over the week test sets can be run multiple times , giving multiple test results under a test set

Currently when i want to get the latest result of each test under a test set i am querying for the distinct test names, and then for each distinct name i am querying for that name and ordering by startDate and startTime to get the latest. This is a pain because when i have a test set with over 100 different tests it degrades substantially.

What im trying to do is to perform what i want in one call of django.objects...

Here is the mysql to effectively represent what i want to achieve:

> select testName,result,MAX(startDate),MAX(startTime),othertestinfo from testset where testset_id = 'UniqueID' group by testName;

Im having a hard time trying to figure this out in django , if its even possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Update 23/1/12

Models for what i am using.

```
class testCase(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    testName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    precision = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fileLocation = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    testset_id = models.ForeignKey(testset)
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    startDate = models.DateField()
    startTime = models.TimeField()

class testset(models.Model):
    testsetID = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    testsetName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    platformName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    osName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    executionName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    software = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    runType = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: You should have a look at the django aggregation documentation here:    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to the following:

```
t = testset.objects.values('testName').annotate(Max('startDate'),Max('startTime'))
```

This would give you a list of the objects' values-dictionaries containing key-value pairs of `testName`, `startDate`, `startTime` for the required condition.

You would get the condition fulfilled in this but you can try experimenting with this to get all the columns.